# Problems with more than four variables in mail() - PHP

Tags: php, email, variables, limit

I am trying to build a form which submit a copy to the form owner and the user. However
when I try to insert a fifth variable into mail() it seems as if the last of the variables  stops working:

```
if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $email_address; //user email
    $email_subject = "Some text";
    $email_body = "more text"; 
    $from = "From: $myemail \n"; //form owner email
    $headers = "Bcc:" . $myemail;

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$from,$headers);

    header("Location: $where");
}
```

Leaving out $from I get a copy of the mail sent to both user and form owner, however no possibility to control the "from"-field of the email - leaving out $header the form owner don't receive a copy. If possible I like both.

I apologize in advance for the simplicity of my question - everything I know about php (and web dev in general) I've picked up from clever guys on fora such as this.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the correct parameters for mail:

`bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`

As you can see, the 4th parameter is not "from", but a headers string.

Try an example like below:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

You put your from, cc, bcc etc fields in the headers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use from like this, please refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php